# Using IOM and Visual Basic in SAS Program Development

Tags: c#, vb.net, sas

Looking at [this](http://www2.sas.com/proceedings/sugi28/032-28.pdf) for example and this line of VB code:

```
Dim obSAS As SAS.Workspace
Dim obWM As New SASWorkspaceManager.WorkspaceManager
```

or C# equivalent:

```
SAS.Workspace obSAS = default(SAS.Workspace);
SASWorkspaceManager.WorkspaceManager obWM = new SASWorkspaceManager.WorkspaceManager();
```

where do I get the dll for SASWorkspaceManager from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to be the SASWMan.dll in C:\Program Files\SASHome2\x86\Integration Technologies